# Php mail reader

Tags: php, email

anybody know any PHP library to read various mail services? Like Hotmail, Gmail, yahoo?

It would be great if the library could parse the email and mark as read...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution might be to use the [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) component of Zend Framework -- if it's as several other components, you could be able to use it outside of the Framework, not having too much work to do to "extract" it.

The documentation page about [Reading Mail Messages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) could interest you.

Answer (score 3):

See the [PHP IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) library. That'll work for Gmail at least.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info but i need a lbrary that non-server dependant (php-imap) i need to download and change my php... Anyway it is great info tho!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the PHP Imap/POP3 library together with pieces from the Horde project to parse attachments. Horde provides a couple of helpful classes to handle MIME encodings.

I downloaded the entire Horde stack and used the individual classes in my application.