# Get Email Message from any email service provider

Tags: php

I've a html message form box where user can send message with php.

Now I'm trying to get email message from any email service provider, Like: yahoo, gmail, hotmail etc. Is there any way to get email message from any email service provider.

Your suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Well, I've not mail sever. I want to test it on my local sever.

Comment: than check http://www.perspicuousasmud.com/2008/10/24/setting-up-a-localhost-mailserver

Comment: He is not asking how to setup an email server, he wants to know how to check other email servers for messages using PHP.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278993/php-mail-reader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the provider allows access via POP3/IMAP, otherwise no. Gmail allows IMAP/POP3 access for free, but it is disabled by default.

Hotmail and Yahoo only provide POP3/IMAP access if you pay for their premium packages.

To read POP3/IMAP messages, first make sure the [IMAP extension](http://php.net/imap) is enabled for your PHP installation. Even though the extension is called IMAP, you use the same set of functions for POP3.

The [introduction page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php) has a comment that includes code to get you started.

Comment: Well, do you have any link or script that i can use in my production

Comment: @Babu see the links Burhan provided. You'll find examples there.

Comment: It's really helpful link @Burhan Khalid. Thank you:)